# how many of relatives are female

Tags: puzzle

I am working on this problem but I am not so sure my answer is right. The question is below with multiples choices but there is only is right.

```
Q: c,d,e,f,g,h and i are the father, mothers, aunt, brother, sister, wife and daughter of j, but you don't know which is which. But you know that

e and f are of the same gender

c and d are not the same gender

h was born before c

f is not the mother of j

Referring to the above, how many of relatives ( d,c,e,f,g,h,i) are females

3 of them

4 of them

5 of them

6 of them

7 of them
```

What is your answer for this problem. I think it is 5

Comment: Problem says that e and f are the same gender. looking at the list it appears that e=aunt and f=brother. so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that we have some relatives of $j$, namely the:

- Father
- **Mother**
- **Aunt**
- Brother
- **Sister**
- **Wife**
- **Daughter**

Then you ask how many of those are females. I do not see the need for any additional information, since we know that a mother, an aunt, a sister, a wife and a daughter (marked with bold) has to be females. This gives the answer 5.

Comment: yeah that is exactly what I thought. I think the additional info just bully us. I just wanna double check my question after all. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Is that the entire problem, or is there some additional question?

Comment: it is entire problem. I took it from IQ test....

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, remember marking it as correct.